# Редактор tinyMCE, где находится файл в корневой папке сайта на ModX, куда нужно добавлять скрипты?

Tags: modx, tinymce

Я новичок. В документации нашла вот это, но куда это добавлять, не сказано:

```
// Add custom Fonts to the Fonts list
if ( ! function_exists( 'wpex_mce_google_fonts_array' ) ) {
    function wpex_mce_google_fonts_array( $initArray ) {
        $initArray['font_formats'] = 'Lato=Lato;Andale Mono=andale mono,times;Arial=arial,helvetica,sans-serif;Arial Black=arial black,avant garde;Book Antiqua=book antiqua,palatino;Comic Sans MS=comic sans ms,sans-serif;Courier New=courier new,courier;Georgia=georgia,palatino;Helvetica=helvetica;Impact=impact,chicago;Symbol=symbol;Tahoma=tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;Terminal=terminal,monaco;Times New Roman=times new roman,times;Trebuchet MS=trebuchet ms,geneva;Verdana=verdana,geneva;Webdings=webdings;Wingdings=wingdings,zapf dingbats';
        return $initArray;
    }
 }
 add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'wpex_mce_google_fonts_array' );
```

Подключила шрифты Sun Fransisco в файле и закинула в путь, начинающийся с /assets/...
Помогите, пожалйста, разобраться

Comment: Сам редактор в админке 4 версии